# Dependence of the permittivity on solvent mixing ratio

Tags: computational-chemistry, solvents, mixtures

I am doing DFT calculations on an organometalloid compound to assess whether it dissociates into an ion pair in different solvents. I suppose that the more polar the solvent is the more stable this compound should be in its dissociated form. To achieve this I want to successively increase the permittivity of the solvent mixture using PCM. It was stated that this compound is  well soluble in a 1:1 mixture of water and acetonitrile and now I am wondering if I can just calculate the mean permittivity value of both solvents and imply it in my PCM calculation to simulate this solvent environment. So my question is if the permittivity is directly proportional to the mixing ratio of two solvents.

Comment: I doubt it's so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consult reference (1) and others cited therein. [Nikitin and Lyubartsev](http://archive.ambermd.org/201704/att-0061/20721_ftp.pdf) explain:

> Experimental data 26 [[Venables and Schmuttenmaer](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.475902)] show that the dielectric permittivity of water–acetonitrile mixture is about linear in terms of the volume ratio.

[image]

*My interpretation* of volume ratio (or more accurately, volume fraction, which is used in Fig. 5) is that it is computed from the equivalent volumes of pure components that would be combined, so it can be translated linearly into a molar fraction. The alternative is that it implies application of a way of computing the partial molar volume of the components, since the density of the mixtures is *not* linear in the mole fraction (see Fig. 4).

*References*

(1) Nikitin, A. M.; Lyubartsev, A. P. New Six-Site Acetonitrile Model for Simulations of Liquid Acetonitrile and Its Aqueous Mixtures. *J. Comput. Chem.* 2007, **28** (12), 2020–2026. https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.20721.

(2) Venables, D. S.; Schmuttenmaer, C. A. Far-Infrared Spectra and Associated Dynamics in Acetonitrile–Water Mixtures Measured with Femtosecond THz Pulse Spectroscopy. *The Journal of Chemical Physics* 1998, **108** (12), 4935–4944. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.475902.

Comment: Hmm, the pic seems rather to be in vol fraction, as it seems to me very  suspicious 1% AN would have so low permitivity. OTOH, why to simulate permitivity of the pure AN?

Comment: Yes, the axis label shows vol% but I assume that is an error and fraction is meant. Also, in the text they speak of vol ratio which is inconsistent. Not the tidiest reference but it links to the experimental source which the OP can consult.

Comment: This helps a lot.